# Publishing artifact from gradle project to bintray (maven repository)

Tags: gradle, release, publish, pom.xml, bintray

I have configured Gradle to publish project artifact using [new Maven Publisher Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html), unfortunately this plugin has problem with dependency in generated `pom.xml` - dependencies has scope `runtime` instead of `compile`.

My configuration is like this:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenCustom(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://api.bintray.com/maven/codearte/public/fairyland"
            credentials {
                username = bintrayUser
                password = bintrayKey
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Publishing was simple with one command:

```
gradle publish
```

How to achieve this in old (working) way? Is possible to automate project taging when project is released?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            name = 'Codearte Public Repository'
            repository(id: 'codearte-repository', url: 'https://api.bintray.com/maven/codearte/public/fairyland'){
                authentication(userName: bintrayUser, password: bintrayKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Uploading with command:

```
gradle uploadArchives
```

Comment: I'd also suggest you take a look at the [bintray gradle plugin](https://bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-jars/gradle-bintray-plugin). It makes publishing to Bintray much easier.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that all POM dependencies have `runtime` scope is a known limitation of the new, incubating `maven-publish` plugin. Until this gets fixed, you can either fix it up yourself by using the `publication.pom.withXml` hook, or fall back to the `maven` plugin. Both plugins are documented in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Tagging is an entirely different question. You can either use one of the third-party Gradle SCM plugins or call out to a command line tool (e.g. with an `Exec` task).

Comment: In my opinion new gradle `maven-plugin` is not new anymore, but problem still exist.

Comment: Is this "new, incubating" plugin ever going to be finished?

Comment: Here is example 'withXml hook' https://gist.github.com/bugs84/b7887fb5d7f9f2d484b8#file-changefromruntimetocompile-gradle which i found here https://discuss.gradle.org/t/maven-publish-plugin-generated-pom-making-dependency-scope-runtime/7494/6 it's working for me

Comment: Is there a bug anywhere tracking this limitation?

Comment: From https://discuss.gradle.org/t/maven-publish-plugin-generated-pom-making-dependency-scope-runtime/7494/5

publishing {
 publications {
     pom.withXml {
         asNode().dependencies.'*'.findAll() {
             it.scope.text() == 'runtime' && project.configurations.compile.allDependencies.find { dep ->
                 dep.name == it.artifactId.text()
             }
         }.each() {
             it.scope*.value = 'compile'
         }
     }
    }
}